# Redefine standard OData service - SAP Gateway NetWeaver

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-fiori, netweaver, sap-gateway

in my project, i'm using Sales_Order_Create Service. In my use case, it is required to change some business logic in the backend: Gateway Netweaver (create deep entity method).
I used the approach of create new Project(child), and then Redefine > OData service(GW). But when i debugg and start my Fiori sales order create app(extended app), i see that it sometimes  still using the standard service methods(Parent) , especially in order creation .

Should i overwrite extended service? but how can i get my standard service again once it's overwritten in case i want to reuse it in other projects ?

If no, is there any solution to modify business logic(redefine methods) in child service?

How to make my Fiori extended application use this child service, (even if i replaced the service with New > Extension > Replace Service).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have created an extension application you need to assign the extension application to the testing user. You need to do this by creating a custom business catalog role(new launch pad .. new application .. new catalog .. new role with tile catalog) and assign it to testing user.

Comment: thank u for your answer, but  my question is not about Fiori Launchpad. My question is there any possibility to redefine methods(business logic) in child service, in sap Gateway Netweaver.  How can i modify child service without affecting the parent(standard service)

Comment: i posted another question to be more specific here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35775404/sap-gateway-netweaver-odata-service-redefinition-and-method-extension